# Cloning source code

Tags: git

Within macOS Catalina, I have used

```
git clone <URL>
```

to clone source code from GitHub.

I want to clone https://opensource.apple.com/source/efax/efax-42/efax/

Is `git clone` not the right command?  How does one clone said source code?

Comment: So your command was `git clone https://opensource.apple.com/source/efax/efax-42/efax/`?

Answer (score 3):

That URL is not for a git repo. That's just a (pretty) file listing. https://opensource.apple.com/releases/ says:

> #### Releases
>
> You can download the open source code for our operating systems and
> developer tools from their respective GitHub pages. Select the release
> you’d like below.

And going down the list, in, e.g., OS X 10.11.6, you can see:

> [image]

which links to https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/efax/archive/efax-42.tar.gz and https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/efax/tree/efax-42. You can download a tarball from the first link and get the URL to clone from the second link.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a Git repository, it's just a batch of files
served by HTTP server. You can download all of them using lftp:

```
lftp  -c 'connect https://opensource.apple.com/source/efax/efax-42/efax/; mirror --exclude-glob *html'
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.  An error was returned.

mirror: regular expression `*html': Invalid preceding regular expression

Comment: @gatorback: sorry, fixed it now

Comment: Clever.  If you provide an explanation of he options, it would not only help me better understand your work: it would help the community as well.  Again, Thank you

Comment: All options are described in `man lftp`

Answer (score 1):

`apple-opensource-downloader` can be used to download from `opensource.apple.com`:

```
 cargo +nightly install apple-opensource-downloader
```

Then you can download it:

```
apple-opensource-downloader component-to-git --no-bare efax efax/efax-42
cd efax/efax-42/efax
git log
git status
```

The `comonent-to-git` and `release-to-git` option:

```
component-to-git      Fetch an Apple open source component and convert to a Git repository
release-to-git        Convert a released entity to a Git repository
```