# How to verify that source code does / does not provide driver for Apple USB modem?

Tags: grep, drivers, macos, source

Source Code: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698474/182280

The goal is to verify that the source code has the driver to support an Apple USB Faxmodem  MA034Z/A.  What are the keywords or phrases to search said source code?

I realize that there may be no keywords and that it may be necessary to plow (read) the code.  If this is the case, please indicate in your answer that you have / have not 'plowed' through the code.

A grep or similar command line example will be given preference to be awarded answer credit.   Likewise a narrative explaining any command options are preferred and will help the community

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to obtain information about a specific piece of software is reading the [README](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/efax/blob/efax-42/efax/README). This one says:

> efax, a small ANSI C/POSIX program that sends and receives faxes using any fax modem (Class 1, 2 or 2.0).

The project is a user-space program. It does not even contain a driver. However, if your Apple USB Faxmodem MA034Z/A happens to come with a driver which exposes the device as a fax modem of the mentioned class, you can use efax.

Comment: Thank you for your response.   The modem did not ship with a driver.  I believe the fax modem's driver was in  MacOS 10.11 El Capitan  and removed in macOS Sierra (10.12).  How did you verify that the [said source code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698474/182280) does not have a modem driver?

Comment: With the readme being a pretty strong indicator, I skimmed the code and noticed [line 92 in efaxos.h](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/efax/blob/f4b6384/efax/efaxos.h#L92). It defines the node of the device the application wants to interact with. It expects the node to exist. A driver (as in "kernel module") would create the node.